# Is there an idiom that means working hard and continuously?

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means working hard continuously? Preferably, I would like an idiom that means "work 24/7 without rest", but I can accept something that means "give as much effort as possible". Most idioms seems to be related to working hard, but doesn't imply it's done continuously without rest.

Comment: Can't think of an idiom but an adverb... *ceaselessly* or adjective *round-the-clock*?

Comment: Assiduous, or any of its synonyms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a good idiom but the word "toil" may be closest to what you mean in English. It suggests not just working hard, but also constantly. You can add words like "ceaseless" or "endless" to emphasize the unending nature of the work, such as, "a life of ceaseless toil."